# Regular Expression for a pattern of 45 hex numbers OR 48 hex numbers - Python

Tags: python, regex

My file contains either 45 hex numbers, separated by whitespaces or 48 hex numbers, separated by whitespaces. I need ALL of those numbers individually and not as a whole. I am currently using a brute force method to get 45 numbers.

```
pattern = re.compile("([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s([0-9a-f]{2})\s")
```

However, even with this, I still cant figure out how to extract the remaining three numbers in a 48 hex number instance. Could you please help me out with simplifying this problem?

I would avoid solutions like the ones below (haven't tried if it works) as I will have to later split the string for each instance i.e. considering it gives proper output!

```
(((?:[0-9a-f]{2})\s){48})|(((?:[0-9a-f]{2})\s){45})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have a space at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When writing long REs, consider using [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#using-re-verbose) to make them more readable.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"""
 ^( [0-9a-fA-F]{2} (?: \s [0-9a-fA-F]{2} ){44}
                (?:(?: \s [0-9a-fA-F]{2} ){3} )? )$ 
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Read as: two hex digits, followed by 44 times (space followed by two hex digits), optionally followed by 3 times (space followed by two hex digits).

Test:

```
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 44))
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 45))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd8f27e0738>
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 46))
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 47))
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 48))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd8f27e0990>
>>> pattern.match(" ".join(["0f"] * 49))
```

Then finally, to retrieve the individual digits, do `.group(0).split()` on the match result. That's much easier than writing an RE that puts all the digits into separate groups.

**EDIT**: alright, here's how to solve the original problem. Just construct the RE dynamically.

```
chunk = r"""([0-9a-fA-F]{2}\s)"""
pattern = re.compile(chunk * 45 + "(?:" + chunk * 3 + ")?")
```

Comment: How do you retrieve each couple of digits?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: retrieve the whole match, then split on whitespace. No need to do that in an RE.

Comment: I see no reason to use an RE, then. Better use an approach that only requires a single line scan.

Comment: Still no match-group for each hex number, but a nice approach of various lengths.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: an RE match should stop when it finds something that cannot possibly match, e.g. when an enormous string is input.

Comment: You do not capture single hexnumbers (hexdigit pairs) as a match group; I understand the asker so that he wants that, and that also is what his hard-wired version does.

Comment: I don't consider 150 characters an enormous string and the OP was asking for a way to parse 45-48 hex numbers. .NET's RE implementation has groups that record their previous matches which would be perfect for this problem.

Comment: @Alfe: true, I missed that requirement at first and went for the pragmatic solution. Feel free to downvote, I won't hold it against you.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: where did the number 150 pop up?

Comment: Rounding up 48 * 2 hex digits and 48 spaces.

Comment: Although you don't capture the hex numbers, I like the style of your RE.

Comment: your answer doesnt put each number in a match group however it solves the problem of getting either 45 or 48 numbers in the shortest possible way. So here, take my upvote :) if the only way to get all numbers is by hardwiring as I did, then yes, yours is the best possible answer to the question. Do let me know. And also please tell me how the optional 3 numbers was implied in the expression

Also note that I do have a space at the end so the format really is "ff ff ... ff "

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use two patterns? That way you don't need complicated logic to deal with the subgroups.

```
pattern1 = re.compile("([0-9a-f]{2}\s){45}")
pattern2 = re.compile("([0-9a-f]{2}\s){48}")
```

Comment: Whitespace != `' '`.  Better use `r'\s+'`.  And somehow take care of the space at the end.  I bet there doesn't have to be one after the last hexdigit pair.

Comment: Yeah I had \s in there, weird... Must've pasted a stale buffer. Fixed it now.

Comment: Still that problem with the trailing space (which your pattern expects and which might not be there).  Can be solved using `r'([0-9a-f]{2}\s+){44}[0-9a-f]{2}'` though.

Comment: But that still does not produce a match objects which has a capture group for each hexnumber.

Comment: Really, these are minor implementation issues. The initial point stands which was "use two patterns".

Comment: Using two patterns does not solve his question which is how to nice-up the hard-wired version which already captures each hexdigit-pair as a single match-group.  Having two patterns also is no solution in case he wanted to use `finditer()`, `findall` or similar on that.

Comment: @Tim, as Alfe said, 
pattern1 will only capture the 45th hex number while pattern 2 will only capture the 48th number

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you may be looking for is [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Depending on how the rest of that string looks.. this worked for me to get me a list of strings for each hex

```
import re
reg = re.compile("[0-9a-f]{2}\s")
hexes = "ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12 ab 12"
hexList = re.findall(reg, hexes)
```

This gets you a **list** of all the 2 char hexes. From there it is trivial to split it to 45/48, depending on what other kind of data is in the string you are grabbing from.

This won't work, however, if you have a ton of data sitting in the string.

Alternatively, although you said you didn't want to do it, it is indeed very trivial to do something like this:

```
reg = re.compile("([0-9a-f]{2}\s){45,48}") #Edit: Missed an open paren
match = reg.search(hexes)
if match:
    splitList = match.group().split()
```

And you then have a list of all the numbers, nicely split up.

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses in regexp string and I understand the asker so that he wants to get all hexnumbers (hexdigit pairs) as captured values.  Your `r'(...){45}'` will capture only one, not all those hexnumbers, even if all are matched.

Comment: Oopsie, missed the parenthesis quickly hammering it out :)

reg.search(hexes) does indeed return all the hexes though. Not just one. http://imgur.com/1Ow0X

Comment: Of course.  But I think the asker wants to have a match object for each "group of 48/45 hex numbers" and in that match object a match-group for each hexnumber.  Maybe I understood him wrong, but that's what he gets with his long hard-wired pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I like your hard-wired approach (for your specific needs, that is), but I would generate the pattern string by multiplication.  My example expects groups of 3 and groups of 5 (just to make it easier in testing):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:' +
  r'\s+'.join([ r'([a-f0-9]{2})' ] * 5) +
  r')|(?:' +
  r'\s+'.join([ r'([a-f0-9]{2})' ] * 3) +
  r')')
m1 = pattern.match('ab cd ef')
m2 = pattern.match('ab cd ef 34 56')
```

The result of `m.groups()` will be something like `(None, None, None, None, None, 'ab', 'cd', 'ef')` for groups of 3 and something like `('ab', 'cd', 'ef', '34', '56', None, None, None)` for groups of 5.  So you can check whether `m.groups()[0]` is None to find ouy which version (45 or 48) you got and then use either groups()[:48] or groups()[48:].

Make sure you have the larger number (48) before the smaller number (45).

This pattern can of course be used with `findall`, `search`, `finditer`, or similar if you have a way to know where one hexnumber group ends and the next begins.  In this example, the whitespace between the hexnumbers must be space or tab, other stuff (like newlines) separates the hexnumber groups from each other:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:' +
  r'[ \t]+'.join([ r'([a-f0-9]{2})' ] * 5) +  # replaced \s by [ \t]
  r')|(?:' +
  r'[ \t]+'.join([ r'([a-f0-9]{2})' ] * 3) +
  r')')
print [ i.groups() for i in pattern.finditer(
    'ab cd ef 34 56\nab cd ef 34 56\nab cd ef\nab cd ef\n') ]
```

→

```
[ ('ab', 'cd', 'ef', '34', '56', None, None, None),
  ('ab', 'cd', 'ef', '34', '56', None, None, None),
  (None, None, None, None, None, 'ab', 'cd', 'ef'),
  (None, None, None, None, None, 'ab', 'cd', 'ef') ]
```

Comment: A non efficient answer but an answer none the less. my upvote! However the answer provided by larsmans is the best.

Comment: It is not non-efficient because all it does is done only on compile time of the regexp; afterwards, the complicated built strings and lists are thrown away.  Also the source isn't as lengthy as your original due to the use of multiplication.  And it is the only solution providing what you asked for (group-capture for each hexnumber).  But anyway; I can understand if you changed your mind on what you wanted after seeing the disadvantages of the way it can be done ;-)  (I would not have done it that way either.)

Comment: the updated answer by larsmans gives me a match group for each number. It also gives exactly that (no 'None' in the generated groups) hence my comment about inefficiency.

Comment: He proposes to use `.group(0).split()` to split the result.  That's two processes, that's what you did not want in your question explicitly and I don't consider it more efficient.  But as I said, I can understand if you prefer it nevertheless.

Comment: You didn't check his updated answer. It gives whats required. no split required.

Comment: Ah, alright.  He now uses also the method to generate the regexp string dynamically using multiplication.  Nevermind.

Comment: I always find it a bit distracting to see a long elaborate solution with flaws and lateron an edit to it which adds a much shorter solution (in this case it was short enought for me to overlook it) which somehow resembles the quintessence of another solution given in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider using `re.findall` ?

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = r'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)'
>>> s= '45f 567B 45C67'
>>> for i in re.findall(pat, s):
    print i


45
567B
45C67
```

With this method no matter how many numbers you have in your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file contains hex data, just read the whole file into a string and then split it on whitespace. This works with 45, 48, or any other numbers.

```
import re
splitter = re.compile('\s+')
data = splitter.split(file(filename,'r').read())
```

Comment: No need for `re`: `open(filename).read().split()` would have the same effect.

Comment: Not if there are multiple whitespace characters in between hex strings. The string split only looks for one character.

Comment: Ah, good point, you're right. But in that case, you should be splitting by `\s`, not `\s+` :)

Comment: \s+ means one or more whitespace characters which is what I want. A \s by itself splits on each individual whitespace character which would be equivalent to the string split.

Comment: Not exactly: `"foo   bar".split()` returns `['foo', 'bar']`.

Comment: I want exactly 45 number match or exactly 48 number match. splitting isnt making the problem easier